# Hibernate - What is the best way to alter the DTYPE?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following inheritance

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

with the @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

Now, when I use `session.save` to insert an instance of C for the first time, the DTYPE column is set to 'C'.
But when I use `session.update` to update an instance of B with the exact identifier and other attribute values of C, hibernate is not updating the DTYPE at all. Here's what hibernate log gave me

> update
> A
> set
> fieldA=?, fieldB=?
> where
> id=?

There is no DTYPE alter. My work around is to separately update the DTYPE using HQL

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query<?> query = session.createQuery("UPDATE A SET DTYPE = :type WHERE id = :id");
    
query.setParameter("type", typeName);
query.setParameter("id", instance.getId());
query.executeUpdate();
```

It works, but I don't think this is the best practice for updating the DTYPE.
Is there a better way of doing this?
Thank you!

Comment: I guess you should not want to update the DTYPE column. If you want it then most likely the `SINGLE_TABLE` is not appropriate chose for your case.

Comment: That's a good point, I guess I'll have to put my design under consideration, thank you so much.